# How do i loop to one page to another in my web scraping project.. should scrap datas from all 250 pages..But it stops in the first page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

#So this is a part of the scrapping code...but it does not gets looped more than the first page please help me to loop all through 250 pages of the etsy ecommerce website

URL = f'https://www.etsy.com/in-en/c/jewelry/earrings/ear-jackets-and-climbers?ref=pagination&page={page}'
try:
#Count for every page of website
URL = URL.format(page)
browser.get(URL)
print("Scraping Page:",page)

```
                #xpath of product table
                
                PATH_1 ='//*[@id="content"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[9]/div/div/div'
                
                #getting total items
                items = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, PATH_1)
                items = items.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li' )
                
                #available items in page
                end_product = len(items)
                
                #Count for every product of the page
                for product in range(0,end_product):
                    print("Scarping reviews for product", product +1)
                    
                    #clicking on product
                    try:
                        items[product].find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').click()
                    except:
                        print('Product link not found')
        
                    #switch the focus of driver to new tab
                    windows = browser.window_handles
                    browser.switch_to.window(windows[1])
                    
                    try:
                        PATH_2 = '//*[@id="reviews"]/div[2]/div[2]'
                        count = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, PATH_2)
                        
                        #Number of review on any page
                        count = count.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'wt-grid wt-grid--block wt-mb-xs-0')
                        for r1 in range(1,len(count)+1):
                            dat1 = browser.find_element(By.XPATH ,
                                        '//*[@id="reviews"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/p'.format(
                                            r1)).text
                            if dat1[:dat1.find(',')-6] not in person:
                                try:
                                    person.append(dat1[:dat1.find(',')-6])
                                    date.append(dat1[dat1.find(',')-6:])
                                except Exception:
                                    person.append("Not Found")
                                    date.append("Not Found")
                                try:
                                    stars.append(browser.find_element(By.XPATH ,
                                        '//*[@id="reviews"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span/span[2]'.format(
                                            r1)).text[0])
                                except Exception:
                                    stars.append("No stars")
                    except Exception:
                    browser.close()
                    
                    #swtiching focus to main tab
                    browser.switch_to.window(windows[0])
                    
                    #export data after every product
                    #export_data()
        
            except Exception as e_1:
                print(e_1)
                print("Program stoped:")
            export_data()
            browser.quit()
        
        #defining the main function
        def main():
            logging.basicConfig(filename='solution_etsy.log', level=logging.INFO)
            logging.info('Started')
            if 'page.txt' in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
                with open('page.txt','r') as file1:
                    page = int(file1.read())
                for i in range(1 ,250):
                    run_scraper(i,browser)
            else:
                for i in range(1,250):
                    with open('page.txt','w') as file:
                        file.write(str(i))
                    run_scraper(i,browser)
            
            export_data()
            print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
            logging.info('Finished')
        
        # Calling the main function 
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
    
    So in this code please help to loop from one page to another where do i apply the loop.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve / format your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks

Comment: Yeah i am quite new to stackoverflow so please do accept my apology @HedgeHog is there any other platform so we can talk precisely

Comment: We are all here to learn - Even on another platform, I would first expect that the question and the example correspond to a certain effort - Why should someone make the effort to help you, if you do not invest this already ;)

Comment: So my problem statement is to scrap all datas from a etsy ecommerce website ..i have written the code and it works perfectly..But it just scraps just the products in the first page..How i make it to run all 250 pages..!

Answer (score 0):

```
stud = 'https://www.etsy.com/in-en/c/jewelry/earrings/ear-jackets-and-climbers?ref=pagination&page={}'
from time import sleep
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
        
for i in tqdm(range(1, 250)):
    url_pages = stud.format(i)
    browser.get(url_pages)
    sleep(4) ## sleep of 4 will rest your code for 4 sec so that the entire page is loded you can adjust it according to your internet speed.
    html = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser)
    ### funtion or anything that you want to apply from here
```

Then follow your steps as you wish this will load all the pages.

If it still not working, look how I have scraped data from multiple pages
from site similar to this site Github link to my solution  : https://github.com/PullarwarOm/devtomanager.com-Web-Scraping/blob/main/devtomanager%20Final.ipynb

The scraped page is similar to page you are trying to scrape so go through this ipynb file. Thank you.

Comment: Precisely where do i apply this loop..!

Comment: It is a idea of structure I hope you understood code till url_pages = stud.format(i), after this code all the pages that you want to scrape will be iterated one after other. but you need to extract url hence, browser.get(url_pages), after that sleep (4) will give time to completely load the page so that you can fetch html code from them and manipulate according to your requirement. Thank you